# Ouath2 Google Meteor

Tags: meteor, oauth, meteor-accounts, service-accounts

Im trying to connect to google using the [Accounts-google](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/accounts-google) package.

I have already install the 2 packages.

```
meteor add service-configuration
meteor add accounts-google
```

This is how my `server/config.js` file looks.

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert(
  { service: "google" },
  {
    $set: {
      clientId: "xxxxxxxx",
      loginStyle: "popup",
      secret: "xxxxx"
    }
  }
);
```

My setup on the google console.

Javascript Origins: `http://localhost:3000/`

redirect URL: `http://localhost:3000/_oauth/google?close`

But im getting always the same error.

[image]

Its clear that the error relays on the redirect url so its there something wrong with this  `http://localhost:3000/_oauth/google?close` ?

I have already follow the steps pointed by Slava at [Github issue #2717](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2717)

Comment: Check your settings for the api key in the Google developer console, to make sure you've added `http://localhost:3000/` to the authorized origins and `http://localhost:3000/_oauth/google` and `http://localhost:3000/_oauth/google?close` to your authorized redirect urls.

Comment: Brian you are the men it work perfect please make an answer witht his to accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your settings for the api key in the Google developer console, to make sure you've added `http://localhost:3000/` to the authorized origins and `http://localhost:3000/_oauth/google` and `http://localhost:3000/_oauth/google?close` to your authorized redirect urls.